# DOMXPath var_dump: "(object value omitted)"

Tags: php, html, xpath, data-extraction

```
$store = curl_exec($ch); // Returns a page of HTML

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($store);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
```

Vardump `$xpath`:

```
object(DOMXPath)#2 (1) { 
    ["document"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
}
```

What is wrong here? I'm trying to use xpath on the HTML code to extract info.

```
object(DOMDocument)#1 (34) {
    ["doctype"]         => string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
    ["implementation"]  => string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
    ["documentElement"] => string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
    ["actualEncoding"]  => string(6) "gb2312" 
    ["encoding"]        => string(6) "gb2312"
    ["xmlEncoding"]     => string(6) "gb2312" 
    ["standalone"]      => bool(true) 
    ...
```

Comment: that's not how xpath works... xpath is a search engine for DOM documents, it's **NOT** the document you loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loadHTMLFile` requires path of the html file not the content of the html file [loadhtmlfile](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php). So your code will be

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("path to html file");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
```

**Edit**

If you want to load from html content use [loadhtml](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($store);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
```

Comment: Can i load from string?

Comment: $dom->loadHTML($string); ??

Comment: even with loadHTML , i'm still getting the error. I did a echo on $store. It has html in it

Comment: @RainbowHat You will have fetch the result. If you directly `var_dump `, it will always give you same result.

Comment: As above has  ["textContent"]=> string(2304) , it means the html in it. How do i actually Fetch the result correctly? $elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail']/div[1]/h3/text()");

Comment: @RainbowHat I don't know how this `query("//*[@id='detail']/div[1]/h3/text()");` works, you can look into documentation.